# Increasing resolutions of pdf graphics in R

Tags: r, pdf

If I'm creating pdf figures in R, is there an input argument analogous to res (for png) that I can use to increase the resolution from the default in the following:

```
pdf("Dsr_2b.pdf")
hist(Dsr,breaks=200,xlim=c(-0.03,0.03),main="Figure 2b: Dsr")
dev.off()
```

Nothing I saw in the documentation seemed to be geared to this.

Comment: I think `pdf` is [vector graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics).

Comment: You may want to consider other types of format for your plot. For a histogram I don't think you need a very high resolution. You may be interested in enhanced metafile format (EMF) or .eps

Comment: to clarify/amplify @d.b.'s comment:  in principle, PDF has no limit to resolution; if you wanted to print your graphic out at billboard size (and could find a suitable printer) you could do that. If your image looks grainy it must have something to do with the way you're rendering it (e.g. pasting into MS Word? wonky PDF viewer?) You need to tell us more about *why* you think you need to increase resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the journal requires a high resolution for all figure files, even when it really isn't necessary. If I understand your (S Rivero's) response, there is no way to enhance pdf resolution in R?

Comment: In response to Ben Bolker's comment - the journal requires minimum resolution. I wasn't aware of the vector graphic vs. pixel distinction, so it may not apply to pdf.

Comment: @BenBolker explained perfectly why. As he mentioned, It depends how your are generating your figures, not how your saving the plots

Comment: If you use `pdf` I highly doubt resolution would be a concern. I would recommend using `cairo_pdf` as it creates plots with embedded fonts.

Comment: if possible you should get clarification from the editorial office. I have had to do all kinds of ugly things (like convert from PDF to high-resolution TIFF) to make journals happy, but you should find out what they really need.  Instructions to authors are often vague and sometimes incorrect.

Comment: I used imagemagick (see [here](https://github.com/bbolker/HIV_LHS/blob/master/figures/mkregtif)) to convert from PDF to TIFF, but if they'll let you submit in PDF that will be better.  Especially for initial submission.